# Adding LIKE plugin under fan page tab

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-like

Is this possible? 
I tried and getting error FBML Error (line 50): unknown tag "fb:like"

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it is tricky. As fan pages are only FBML, the only way I found is to load some html code thought an Ajax call, and that code contains an iframe (which will be a page containing your fb:like social plugin).

Problem is that facebook doesn't allow to autorun code, you need the user to click on a link or a picture to make this happen.

You can try this solution, replacing "http://www.helloworld.com/iframe.php" by a valid page with you like button:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=262170#p262170